# How to update the IAM policy that IAM role to have the same permission set the IPs have?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

How to update the IAM policy below so that the IAM role, `arn:aws:iam::7574333677569:role/dev-abc-webserver`, also have permissions?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1517260196123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1432661968133",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pdf.abc.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "24.237.272.151/32",
                        "42.69.252.185/32",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue I faced is that  The IAM role doesn't have permission with it currently,
I want the IAM role to have the same permission set as the IPs have.

We don't need to change the policy
, We need to expand what it already grants access to the provided IAM role.
So ""Condition": {" needs to be expanded so we are checking for our IPs or the IAM role.

I am not able to figure out how to provide access via the IAM role yet.
I did check some aws documentation but not able to figure it out .
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html

Could anyone Help me with this issue, any help should be appreciated?

Comment: You need another statement, multiple conditions in the same statement are always `AND`ed, never `OR`ed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multiple-conditions-eval *"[condition] needs to be expanded so we are checking for our IPs **or** the IAM role.*" is therefore explicitly not possible.

Comment: Could you describe a bit > I want the IAM role to have the same permission set as the IPs we have.  want to expand the policy what it already grants access to the provided IAM role .

Answer (score 1):

Since multiple conditions within a statement are always `AND`ed and never `OR`ed you need a second statement to grant the permission to other entities. That statement will have a different `Principal` and the `Condition` can be removed.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1517260196123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1432661968133",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pdf.abc.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "24.237.272.151/32",
                        "42.69.252.185/32",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, {
            "Sid": "StmtForRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::7574333677569:role/dev-abc-webserver"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pdf.abc.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```